# Piping a bash variable into awk and storing the output

Tags: bash, awk

To illustrate my problem,

```
TEST="Hi my name is John"
OUTP=`echo $TEST | awk '{print $3}'`
echo $OUTP
```

What I would expect this to do is pass the $TEST variable into awk and store the 3rd word into $OUTP.

Instead I get "Hi: not found", as if it is expecting the input to be a file.  If I pass just a string instead of a variable, however, there is no problem.  What would be the best way to approach this?

Thanks all!

Comment: Are you using backticks to assign to TEST.  Copy and paste from the script that gives the error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST="Hi my name is John"
set -- $TEST
echo $3

#!/bin/bash
TEST="Hi my name is John"
var=$(echo $TEST|awk '{print $3}')
echo $var
```

Comment: This seems to work in the command prompt, but when run as a shell script I still get Hi: not found.  Any way to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I was putting an extra space before the $ when setting the variable.  Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: How to tell awk if string is name print a variable before it?

Comment: How to do this with numbers? `var=$( echo "(2+3)" | awk '{print $3}') => 5`

Comment: In stack overflow it is not desirable to just dump code. Please it needs some edit and further explanation.

Answer (score 5):

In one line :

```
echo $(echo "Hi my name is John" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for me, as-is.

```
[bloom@little-cat-a ~]$ TEST="Hi my name is John"
[bloom@little-cat-a ~]$ OUTP=`echo $TEST | awk '{print $3}'`
[bloom@little-cat-a ~]$ echo $OUTP
name
```

Answer (score 1):

As with others, this works for me as-is, but perhaps adding double-quotes (`"`) around `$TEST` in line 2 would help.  If not, more specific information about the system on which you are running bash might help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to reproduce similar behavior:

```
$ alias echo='echo;'
$ echo Hi
Hi: command not found
$ alias
alias echo='echo;'
$ unalias echo
$ echo Hi
Hi
```